# import tidy ImportError: No module named tidy

Tags: python, django

Tried installing [PyTidyLib](http://countergram.com/open-source/pytidylib/docs/index.html#installing-html-tidy), but it did not work. Any idea which is the correct package to get tidy?

Comment: pip install pytidylib

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work?

Comment: I was doing "import tidy" and was not able to find tidy even after installing pytidylib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may help you

> sudo apt-get install python-uTidylib

`

Comment: How to install on mac ?

Comment: Mine worked with `sudo apt-get install python-tidylib`